# Toggle button on Bootstrap 3.2 won't collapse

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

The mobile nav in my Bootstrap site won't collapse. I'm running version 3.2 on this site. I have tried everything I can think of and nothing has worked. I also checked other sites that I've built with Bootstrap and everything is still working fine there. What am I missing here?

Here is my HTML:

```html
<body>
 <div class="topbar" id="page">
        <div class="col-xs-12 mobile-nav">
        <div class="container">
            <!--add this where you want the button to be displayed-->

<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                 
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    
  </div><!--navbar-header--> 
</div>
</div>
            
        </div><!--closes container-->
        <div class="nav-wrap navbar-fixed-top fix-nav">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-2 col-md-1">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/ttmheadlogo.png" class="img-responsive logo" alt="thank the monkey local mobile coupons logo link home" /></a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-11 nav-text">
                    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">                
                        <ul class="col-sm-12 list-unstyled nav nav-justified">
                            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                            <li><a href="consumers.html">CONSUMERS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="business.html">BUSINESSES</a></li>
                            <li><a href="media.html">MEDIA PARTNERS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div><!--closes container-->
    </div><!--closes col-xs-12-->
    </div><!-- closes topbar -->
```

Comment: Can you include the HTML you're using to call the CSS and JQuery Javascript in your site?

Comment: I included everything except for the content for the page. You can view it here: http://collabedit.com/88yb6 . It was just too long to post in a comment :)

Let me know if I need to add the content back & I will.

Comment: My custom css file is also at: collabedit.com/bqb5w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've got a few extra div tags that are causing the issue. If you rework the navigation area a bit (shown below) you should be good to go. I'll paste what I got working, you'll just need to figure out how you want to incorporate your logo (I took that out when troubleshooting):

```html
 <div class="topbar" id="page">
        <div class="col-xs-12 mobile-nav">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>

                    </div><!--navbar-header-->
                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                            <li><a href="consumers.html">CONSUMERS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="business.html">BUSINESSES</a></li>
                            <li><a href="media.html">MEDIA PARTNERS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div><!--closes container-->
        </div><!--closes col-xs-12-->
    </div><!-- closes topbar -->
```